# Who am I, and where do I live?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> In the south of the north of the north
>
> Lies a castle to which a king came forth
>
> Amen to the prince who mourns
>
> To whom the crown adorns

**Who am I?**

Hint:

> The word **Amen** is more important than it may seem. It’s an abbreviation.

Hint 2:

> The answer is a character of a video game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> The Lich King (Warcraft Universe)

And you live in

> The Icecrown Citadel, in the South of Icecrown (which is in the north of Northrend) 
>  Amen is Arthas Menethil, a former prince or Lordaeron. He killed his father to become the king, found the cursed blade Frostmourne, and became the Lich King

Comment: Nice! You even got the amen bit!

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Robb Stark from the book series A Song of Ice and Fire, who lived in Winterfell?

---

In the south of the north of the north

> Winterfell is in the southern part of the nothern half of the North.

Lies a castle to which a king came forth

> King Robert Baratheon visits Winterfell in the first book.

Amen to the prince who mourns

> Robb's father, Ned, is executed in the final scenes of the first book.

To whom the crown adorns

> Robb is later declared King of the North.

Comment: Nice answer! Alas, not quite what I had in mind..

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> **Arthas Menethil** (Warcraft 3)

In the south of the north of the north
Lies a castle to which a king came forth

> Arthas went to Northrend, which is a quite chilly place

Amen to the prince who mourns

> AMen = Arthas Menethil, mourns can be  a reference to the cursed sword Frostmourne

To whom the crown adorns

> He then becomes the Lich King

Comment: You've got it, but you were beaten by mere seconds..

Comment: Indeed :(. Well done Florian !